# How to implement multiple testing for scipy.stats tests

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, statsmodels

I have a dataframe of values from various samples from two groups. I performed a scipy.stats.ttest on these, which works perfectly, but I am a bit concerned here with the fact that so much testing may yield multiple testing error.

And I wonder how to implement MTC (multiple testing correction) with this. I mean, is there some function in scipy or statsmodels which would perform directly the tests and apply MTC on the output series of p-value, or can I apply an MTC function on a list of p-value without problem?

I know that statsmodels may comprise such functions, but what it has in power, it lacks greatly in manageability and documentation, unhappily (indeed, that's not the fault of the developers, they are three for such huge project). Anyway, I am a little stuck here, so I'll gladly take any suggesting. I didn't ask this in CrossValidated, because it is more related to the implementation part than the statistical part.

Comment: statsmodels has standard multiple testing p-value corrections, and tukey-hsd for all pairwise comparisons. http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/stats.html#multiple-tests-and-multiple-comparison-procedures

Comment: What's the relationship between your samples and groups? Are these independent comparisons. p-value correction for multiple testing always applies, but for specific comparisons there exist tests that have higher power than the "generic" p-value corrections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit 9th Oct 2019:
this link works as of today 
https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.multitest.multipletests.html

### original answer (returns 404 now)

[statsmodels.sandbox.stats.multicomp.multipletests](http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.sandbox.stats.multicomp.multipletests.html#statsmodels.sandbox.stats.multicomp.multipletests) takes an array of p-values and returns the adjusted p-values. The documentation is pretty clear.